# Pulling edges up

Tags: edges, bevel, extrude

I'm a newbie to the blender, and I'm making a drink can.

[image]

I have done this so far, and I'm trying to pull selected orange edges up like in this picture(the bottom one is an example).

[image]

I pressed the  <kbd>G</kbd> to grab it, and nothing worked.

I also tried pressing the  <kbd>E</kbd> +  <kbd>Z</kbd> to extrude along the Z axis and bevel (Shift + ctrl + B), but it didn't work at all.

Any good suggestion for this one?

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 1):

Blender has many keyboard shortcuts and many different contexts you might want to use them in so you have to hover the mouse over the area you intend to send keystrokes to. That's one of few possible reasons why nothing happens if you press <kbd>G</kbd>. If your mouse is somewhere else then your 3d viewport the keystroke will be sent there. For example over the Text Editor it will just type letters you press because that's what you want with the Text Editor.

<kbd>G</kbd> is the right key for moving stuff pretty much everywhere stuff can be moved in Blender so when you hit it while hovering the mouse over 3d viewport where you have some mesh elements selected in Edit Mode, 'grab' operation will start. You can move stuff freely and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> or simply click to finish the operation(<kbd>Esc</kbd> or rightclick to cancel), or you could constrain the movement to some axis while in operation with <kbd>X</kbd>,<kbd>Y</kbd> and <kbd>Z</kbd> as well as use numerical input to move stuff precisely. See the [documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/editing/transform/move.html) for more info. Have a look at [Transform Control](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/editing/transform/control/index.html) as well.

One more possible reason why one might not be able to move stuff is if the object is scaled to 0 in some axis. In that case, when you move mesh elements, they get moved in local object's space, but in global space the object is 0 length in some direction, so nothing actually moves. Check if that's the case:

[image]

If it is the case, you could apply scale in object mode with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>:

[image]